# Xml Parsing in android

Tags: android, xml

Guys, can any one tell me that how we parse the xml which is stored in data/data/com.ex.xmlfile/files/new.xml in android.

Comment: accept answers from your previous questions to get help.

Comment: You need to give additional information. Or simply look at http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAXParser . check this it will work simply great

http://java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use saxparser.

Take a look here:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/

and also here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you have three choices: SAX, DOM, and XMLPullParser.  This IBM developer works [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) has a good comparison of all three options.